# SMSC95xx using external PHY (TI DP83TC811): eth1 link is down

Tags: linux, networking, embedded, yocto

on our target board we have an LAN89530 IC embedded to the board connected to the USB2 Pins of the SoC. We are using kernel version 5.4. I enable the driver in themenuconfig and the drivers are getting probed. Also the external PHY is registered and I see it on the log:

[    9.407418] TI DP83TC811 usb-001:002:00: attached PHY driver [TI DP83TC811] (mii_bus:phy_addr=usb)

The issue is that the link is still down and I dont know how to fix that, since this interface is quiet important for our project.

[    9.428773] smsc95xx 1-1:1.0 eth1: Link is Down

Anybody of you facing the same issue here? How to fix that to get the link up and running. It is a 100Mbit Full-Duplex Ethernet communication

Best regards

Daniel Costa-Behrens

Comment: Hi Daniel, did you just look at the link state or did you also tried to plug in a cable. The link only becomes ready when, well, there's an actual link. If so, what does `ip a` say? Have you tried to set the link up manually?

Comment: Hello. I solved the issue to just write in the driver source code of the TI PHY in the config_init function the AUTO PHY register bit 6 to 1. It enables the autodetect of the link during the initialization of thr PHY. Per default this config is not there just the WoL capability so I add this one register setting there and it gets the link up after booting the kernel. Sometimes we just need to read the datasheet of the chip carefully to setup correctly the PHY to our needs. :)